# Change Http Version on XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

My https request to some url failed.
This request was created using XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript.

I checked the requests using a tool.
A request using http 1.1 succeeded.
A request using http 1.0 didn't succeed for the same url.
(each request were created in different application)
(The application request failed was office web addin.
The application request succeed was firefox addin.)

Then, how to switch http version of XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript?
Or is it impossible and depend on application whether 1.0 or 1.1?

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.addEventListener('loadend', function () {
    console.log("req.status >> " + req.status);
});
req.open("GET", "https://www.example.com");
req.send();
```

Comment: So you determined, for sure, that the *office web addin* uses HTTP/1.0 - or are you guessing that just because it fails?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you say, I guess I failed because of HTTP1.0. But it may be caused by other reason. It's good information for me that it is used HTTP1.0.

Comment: no, I didn't say that at all - I asked if you are sure office web addin uses HTTP/1.0

Comment: Oh, sorry. I checked in each requests from office addin and firefox addin using some tool. then succeeded 1.1 request from firefox addin, but failed 1.0 request from office addin. So I assume whether succeed or not may depend on the http version. it is juat a first assumption. So i want to know how to change http version of XMLHttpRequest on JavaScript. thank you.

Comment: right .... have you tried http/1.0 elsewhere to determine if the HTTP version is actually the problem? All you have determined is that firefox addin works and office addin doesn't ... you have not determined that the HTTP version is the problem

Comment: Oh, wait ... if office does use HTTP/1.0 then it is likely that it doesn't use XMLHttpRequest version 2 ... so, no `loadend` event ... you'll want to use old way of waiting for request to finish using  `req.onreadystatechange` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange#Example

Comment: Sorry, but I can retrieve datas using HTTP1.0 on firefox. So depend on another reason. Sorry again and thank you for your reply. later I delete this thread.

Comment: I'd say the issue is with not getting a `loadend` event in that case